# Edit font with font forge

Tags: truetype-fonts, fontforge

I downloaded and installed FontForge(2012 release) and I picked up a TTF file to it. But when I go Save or Export, Windows can't find the savefile nor exported font, while FontForge can. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the font, not save it.

[Here's an explanation](http://sayamindu.randomink.org/conv_guide/ch02s02.html), quoted below for posterity:

> To save files, simply use File->Save as . This saves the font being edited as a *.sfd file.
>
> However, to get an actual usable font, you must use File->Export . In our situation we will be mostly exporting Truetype fonts (which have the GSUB and GPOS tables). However, Fontforge can export in a variety of other formats - take a look at the official documentation for a description of all the supported formats.

Comment: That also occurs when I export.

Comment: When you export the file, it should be in a .ttf format. You then need to install the font. Are you not able to find where it was exported? I must not be sure of what your actual problem is.

Comment: It now mysteriously solved. I think I forgot to press F5 on Explorer...